# Limit of one function given limits of another

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

If a certain function $f$ is known to have the properties

$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 4 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 6,
$$

how would I determine if

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1+3x}{3+f(\frac{1}{x})}
$$

exists, and if it does, compute its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have that $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=6 \Rightarrow\lim_{u\to0^+}{f(\frac{1}{u})}=6.$So the limit that you want is $\frac{1}{9}$

Comment: Could you explain how exactly the limit of f(1/x) as x approaches 0 from the right is 6?

Comment: substitute u=1/x, when x goes to +oo then u goes to 0+

Answer (score 0):

Set $y:= 1/x;$

$\lim_{ y \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{1+3/y}{3+f(y)}.$

Can you take it from here?